# DBSCAN : Retrieve IDs and not latitude/longitude

Tags: python, django, scipy, dbscan

I managed to cluster thousands of geographical locations from my database with DBSCAN. How to retrieve arrays with ids of each cluster, and not lists of latitude/longitude ?

---

To be more precise:

I have a database with several thousands locations (model ThePlace):

```
id   |   placeLat          | placeLng<BR>
1     |  -0.72840701       |  1.07480303<BR>
2     |  0.56603302        | -0.71806147<BR>
3     |  -0.85542777       | 0.80393827<BR>
4     |  0.6079188         | -0.65524001<BR>
5     |  -0.68533746       | 0.5591115<BR>
6     |  0.54826708        | -0.80626836<BR>
7     |  0.89279842        | -0.68575192<BR>
8     |  0.46384115        | -0.66288763<BR>
................
```

Etc, etc.

Here is the code in Django:

```
allplaces = ThePlace.objects.all()
centers = [[place.placeLat, place.placeLng] for place in allplaces]
print(centers)
```

which returns:

```
[[69.6140162630014, 26.8535041809082], [10.791441, 79.1368305], [52.6237376, -3.83939629999998], [21.6229701, -81.5629847], [46.798924, -71.224765], [31.5051046, -5.9447371],    #etc...
```

I then implemented the code suggested by DBSCAN demo:

```
X, labels_true = make_blobs(n_samples=numberofplaces, centers=centers, cluster_std=0.4, random_state=0)
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.01, min_samples=2).fit(X)
core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
labels = db.labels_
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
print("1st cluster:")
print(X[labels == 0])
```

which returns:

```
[[ 0.69845443 -0.12814653] [ 0.64770332 -0.14093706] [ 0.69437909 -0.13627011] [ 0.67780877 -0.12647872] [ 0.71573886 -0.09318022] [ 0.6779438  -0.13639582]]
```

I would like to get arrays with **IDs** of each location, and not arrays with latitudes/longitudes. Is it possible?

For example, I would like to get:

```
[[ 2, 4, 5, 12] [3, 7, 11] [5, 9, 21]   .....  ]
```

I am using Python 2.7 / Django 1.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution to this issue:

```
def clusterplaces(request):
    allplaces = ThePlace.objects.all()
    centers = [[place.placeLat, place.placeLng] for place in allplaces]
    ids = [place.id for place in allplaces]
    # Epsilon in kms
    epsilon = 9
    arr = np.array(centers)
    dist_matrix = np.array([earth_distance(a, b) for a in arr for b in arr]).reshape(arr.shape[0], arr.shape[0])
    db = DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, min_samples=2, metric='precomputed').fit(dist_matrix)
    id_cluster = [(a, b) for (a, b) in zip(db.labels_, ids)]
    id_cluster.sort()

    for a, group in groupby(id_cluster, key=itemgetter(0)):
        print a, [item[1] for item in list(group)]

    return HttpResponse('Everything went ok')
```

Which returns:

```
-1 [69, 5477, 5578, 5579, 5640, 8357, 8375, 12147, 12294, 13837, 14719, 14916, 14919, 15739, 16128, 16288, 16491, 18765, 18814]
0 [104, 3758, 3759, 3760, 3761]]
1 [18705, 18706, 18707, 18709, 18710, 18711, 18712, 18713, 18714, 18715, 18716, 18717, 18718, 18719, 18720, 18721, 18722, 18723, 18725, 18726, 18727, 18729, 18730, 18731, 18732, 18733, 18734, 18735, 18736, 18737, 18738, 18739, 18740, 18741, 18742, 18744, 18745, 18746, 18747, 18748, 18749, 18750, 18752, 18753, 18754, 18755, 18757, 18758, 18759, 18760, 18761, 18762, 18763, 18764, 18876, 18877]
2 [14723, 14724, 14725, 14801, 14802, 14920, 14922, 14923, 15023]
3 [18799, 18800, 18801, 18805, 18806, 18807]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `labels`.

That array are your labels. Every *index* is the object ID, and the value is the cluster number.

`labels == 0` are the objects IDs in your first cluster.

See your last line, you use this as an index into your data array `X`.

Don't use `StandardScaler` on geographic coordinates. You are scaling your world, does that make sense? I'd rather use the `"haversine"` metric instead, and work with distances in meters.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understand that each cluster has a label. What I would like is to get dictionaries of location IDs instead of dictionaries of lat/lng. I reformulated my question above to be more precise. Thanks a lot for the last comment on StandardScaler. I changed it and it works better like that.

Comment: The `labels` is per object, not per cluster. But it *is* what you want, just stored efficiently. You need to look up one numpy function to get the non-zero indexes of `labels == 0`.